# Formatting CSV file to export it as DXF?

Tags: polygon, point, coordinates, csv, dxf

I want to use this [online converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/conversion) to convert a `csv` file to a `dxf` file.

The data I have in my database goes like this:

```
| Point | Poligono        | Name  | Coords X  | Coords Y   | Level(Z) |
|-------|-----------------|-------|-----------|------------|----------|
| 1     | 07-16-015-PAG_H | 26078 | 201851.43 | 8398907.64 | 4260     |
| 2     | 07-16-015-PAG_H | 26079 | 201878.68 | 8398885.14 | 4260     |
| 3     | 07-16-015-PAG_H | 26080 | 201930.19 | 8398828.74 | 4260     |
| 4     | 07-16-015-PAG_H | 26080 | 202025.74 | 8398893.47 | 4260     |
| 5     | 07-16-015-PAG_H | 26081 | 201977.81 | 8398970.05 | 4260     |
| 6     | 07-16-015-PAG_H | 26082 | 201851.43 | 8398907.64 | 4260     |
| 7     | 07-16-014-TMF   | 26083 | 201835.19 | 8398922.77 | 4260     |
...
```

**How do I format this data in a `.csv` file so that I can convert it to a `.dxf` file?**

For example, something like this:

```
id,polygon,name,x,y,z
1,07-16-015-PAG_H,26078,201851.43,8398907.64,4260
...
```

Comment: Hi Levi.  You're asking two quite distinct questions here, could you try keeping to the one question and perhaps raising a new post for the second part.

Comment: Ok i'd delete second one

Comment: I would convert the csv to a Shapefile first and then to a dxf.

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try and do this?